# Filter python pandas dataframe by grouping multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a little hard to explain so bear with me please.

Assume I have a table, like below

[image]

How can I create a new dataframe, that matches criteria below

1. Has 5 rows, for each row, will be values from Column A that between a range, say that first row are between (200, 311), second row between (312, 370) etc.
2. Has 3 columns, for each column, will be values from Column B that between a range, say that first column are between (1, 16), second column between (17, 50) etc.
3. Value of each cell, will be sum of values from Column C which matches corresponding Column and Row.

Example:

[image]

Any illustration?  Numbers are random, you don't need to follow my example.

Thanks a lot!

---

My solution was pre-define row criteria and column criteria in two lists, then run embedded loops to fill each cell value into new dataframe. It works and not that slow, but I am wondering since this is pandas dataframe, there should be a way doing so in query, without any loop.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) to get your ranges, and then supply them to [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to get the sums:

```
# Setup example data.
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(200, 601, size=n),
    'B': np.random.randint(1, 101, size=n),
    'C': np.random.randint(25, size=n)
    })

# Use cut to get the ranges.
a_bins = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[200, 311, 370, 450, 550, 600], include_lowest=True)
b_bins = pd.cut(df['B'], bins=[1, 16, 67, 100], include_lowest=True)

# Pivot to get the sums.
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=a_bins, columns=b_bins, values='C', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

The resulting output:

```
B           [1, 16]  (16, 67]  (67, 100]
A                                       
[200, 311]       82       118        153
(311, 370]       68        56         45
(370, 450]       41       129         40
(450, 550]       32       121         57
(550, 600]        0       112         47
```

Comment: Thanks, so what if I have an interval which is just equal to a particular number? Say c = 333, instead of between a range. How I define this in the bin?

Comment: Assuming you only have integer values, you can define a bin of length 1, e.g. in `pd.cut` use `bins=[...,332, 333, ...]`, and if it's your first bucket omit the `include_lowest=True` so the lower value isn't included.  This would give you `(332, 333]` as a bucket, which would include 333 but not 332.  This won't work if you have floats though, as 332.8 is included in `(332, 333]`, so another method would be necessary in that case.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Such a simple question ...Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I really like [@root's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43055198/5741205)! Here is a slightly modified one-liner version, which uses [pd.crosstab](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) method:

```
In [102]: pd.crosstab(
     ...:     pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[200, 311, 370, 450, 550, 600], include_lowest=True),
     ...:     pd.cut(df['B'], bins=[1, 16, 67, 100], include_lowest=True),
     ...:     df['C'],
     ...:     aggfunc='sum'
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[102]:
B           [1, 16]  (16, 67]  (67, 100]
A
[200, 311]       31       157        117
(311, 370]       23        90         38
(370, 450]      110       168         60
(450, 550]       37       117        115
(550, 600]       35        19         49
```

Comment: Thanks, so what if I have an interval which is just equal to a particular number? Say c = 333, instead of between a range. How I define this in the bin?

Comment: @Windtalker, use `np.arange` or `np.linspace` for generating bins